# When "For all $a,b\in \Bbb Z,$ $a^n|b^m$ implies $a|b$""

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> $m\le n$ if and only if "For all $a,b\in \Bbb Z,$ $a^n|b^m$ implies $a|b$"

I can prove the sufficient condition part, by noting that $a^m|b^m$, which implis $a|b$. But I got stuck on the necessary condition part.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $ $ if $\,m> n\,$ then $ (c^m)^n\mid (c^n)^m,\,$ but $\, c^m\nmid c^n\ $ if $\, c > 1$

Comment: For the other direction a nice way is to use the Rational Root Test [as here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/688644/242), but maybe that's what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be a prime and $x\in \mathbb{N} $ be such that $p^x |a $ and $p^{x +1}\nmid a.$ Let $y\in \mathbb{N}$ be a such that $p^y |b $ and $p^{y +1}\nmid b.$
Since $a^n | b^m $ we have $$nx \leq  my$$ but since $m\leq n$ therefore $$y\geq x$$ and as consequnce $a|b.$